# Mongodb gitlab CI docker connection refused

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a docker test enviroment for our opensource hobby project. Our python and angular code is running without errors. I need a little help with configuring the docker runner to include mongodb.

```
stages: 
- build
- test

services:
  - mongo

variables:
  MONGODB_URI: "mongodb://mongo/projekt_eszkozok"


build: 
  stage: build
  image: "python:3.8.2"
  script:
    - "pip3 install -r sources/backend/requirements.txt"

test:
  stage: test
  image: "python:3.8.2"
  script:
    - "pip3 install -r sources/backend/requirements.txt"
    - cd sources/backend
    - "python -m unittest discover tests/"
```

The error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Also it might matter that the project have Angular frontend which is going to be added to the test enviroment once we made our first Angular test.

Python database config:

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'host': 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/projekt_eszkozok'
}
```

Also tried with:

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'host': 'mongodb://mongo:27017/projekt_eszkozok'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As yippie-flu and Vishesh Kumar Singh
answered in [MongoDB server doesn't start at gitlab runner using gitlab-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391372/mongodb-server-doesnt-start-at-gitlab-runner-using-gitlab-ci), instead of `localhost:27017`, you have to use `mongo:27017` because the mongo service is running in its own Docker container.